# Cloud9 "Unable to load http preview" Flask project

Tags: python, flask, cloud9

I'm following  a mooc for building quickly a website in flask.
I'm using  Cloud9 but i'm unable to watch my preview on it, i get  an :

"Unable to load http preview" :
[image]

the code is really simple, here the views.py code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
# Config options - Make sure you created a 'config.py' file.
app.config.from_object('config')
# To get one variable, tape app.config['MY_VARIABLE']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world !"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And the preview screen, is what I get when I execute

```
python views.py
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you need to make `FLASK_APP` environment variable, and flask application is not running like `python views.py` but `flask run`. [Quick start](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)

```
# give an environment variable, give the absolute path or relative 
# path to you flask app, in your case it is `views.py`
export FLASK_APP=views.py

#after this run flask application
flask run
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but i got the same result with your method.
 When I tried to do it on my physical computer and not on cloud9, it worked. So I guess the probleme should come from cloud9 initial access settings .

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. There is no way we can preview http endpoints directly. Although in AWS documentation they have asked to follow [certain steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-app-preview-http), but those too wont work. Only way is to access it using instance public address and exposing required ports. [Read here for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55977339/2713029)